# Azure Python SDK data tables

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-sdk-python

I need help to get through this workflow.
I have 2 storage accounts which I name `storage1` and `storage2`

`storage1` contrains a list of tables with some data in, and I would like to loop through all those tables, copy their content into `storage2`. I tried with azCopy but I had no luck as this feature is available only in azCopy v7.3 and I couldn't find this version for MacOs M1. The other option is Data factory but its too complex for what I want to achieve. So I decided to go with azure Python sdk.

As a library I am using `azure.data.tables import TableServiceClient`

The code I wrote looks like this:

```
from azure.data.tables import TableServiceClient
my_conn_str_out = 'storage1-Conn-Str'

table_service_client_out = TableServiceClient.from_connection_string(my_conn_str_out)
list_table = []
for table in table_service_client_out.list_tables():
    list_table.append(table.table_name)

my_conn_str_in = 'Storage2-Conn-str'

table_service_client_in = TableServiceClient.from_connection_string(my_conn_str_in)
for new_tables in table_service_client_out.list_tables():
    table_service_client_in.create_table_if_not_exists(new_tables.table_name)
    print(f'tables created successfully {new_tables.table_name}')
```

this is how I structured my code.

```
for table in table_service_client_out.list_tables():
    list_table.append(table.table_name)
```

I loop through all my tables in the storage account and append them into a list.

then:

```
for new_tables in table_service_client_out.list_tables():
    table_service_client_in.create_table_if_not_exists(new_tables.table_name)
    print(f'tables created successfully {new_tables.table_name}')
```

I create the same table in the `storage2`

So far everything works just fine.

What I would like to achieve now, is to query `all` the data in each table in `storage1` and pass it to the respective table in `storage2`

According to Microsoft documentation I can achieve the query table using this:

```
query = table_service_client_out.query_tables(filter=table)
```

so I integrated this in my loop like this:

```
for table in table_service_client_out.list_tables():
    query = table_service_client_out.query_tables(filter=table)
    list_table.append(table.table_name)
    print(query)
```

When I run my python code, I get back the memory allocation of the query and not the data in the tables:

```
<iterator object azure.core.paging.ItemPaged at 0x7fcd90c8fbb0>
<iterator object azure.core.paging.ItemPaged at 0x7fcd90c8f7f0>
<iterator object azure.core.paging.ItemPaged at 0x7fcd90c8fd60>
```

I was wondering if there is a way how I can query all the data in my tables and pass them to my `storage2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
from azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice import TableService,ListGenerator

table_service_out = TableService(account_name='', account_key='')
table_service_in = TableService(account_name='', account_key='')

#query 100 items per request, in case of consuming too much menory load all data in one time
query_size = 100

#save data to storage2 and check if there is lefted data in current table，if yes recurrence
def queryAndSaveAllDataBySize(tb_name,resp_data:ListGenerator ,table_out:TableService,table_in:TableService,query_size:int):
    for item in resp_data:
        #remove etag and Timestamp appended by table service
        del item.etag
        del item.Timestamp
        print("instet data:" + str(item) + "into table:"+ tb_name)
        table_in.insert_entity(tb_name,item)
    if resp_data.next_marker:
        data = table_out.query_entities(table_name=tb_name,num_results=query_size,marker=resp_data.next_marker)
        queryAndSaveAllDataBySize(tb_name,data,table_out,table_in,query_size)


tbs_out = table_service_out.list_tables()

for tb in tbs_out:
    #create table with same name in storage2
    table_service_in.create_table(tb.name)
    #first query 
    data = table_service_out.query_entities(tb.name,num_results=query_size)
    queryAndSaveAllDataBySize(tb.name,data,table_service_out,table_service_in,query_size)
```

Of course, this is a simple demo for your requirement.For more efficiency, you can also query table data by partition key and commit them [by batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cosmosdb-table/azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice.tableservice?view=azure-python#commit-batch-table-name--batch--timeout-none-)

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: this is really good. How about if the data already exists? is there a way how to ignore it if already exists?

Comment: You can use try python try except :https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp , in try section , you just use insert_entity function,  if this item already exists, in except, you can do nothing or using update_entity function:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cosmosdb-table/azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice.tableservice?view=azure-python#update-entity-table-name--entity--if-match------timeout-none-  to cover this existed item.

Comment: I went with `insert_or_replace_entity` to save some line of code and pretty much does what I needed. A think I couldn't find I the method related to the tables `create_table_if_not_exists` as my scripts run every 6hours, it keeps throwing an error that the table already exists, if I wanted to ignore the table if exists and simply update the files inside, should I go with a try and catch as you suggested earlier or there is a specific method that I can call to achieve this?

Comment: Based on official demo, create_table_if_not_exists is the one that most meet your requirement, if it throws exceptions and stop running, I think yes, you can use try-catch to solve it.

Comment: If I use that method I got this error `AttributeError: 'TableService' object has no attribute 'create_table_if_not_exists'` which I find it very weird.

Comment: Oh, yes, I just noticed it, seems the function has been remvoed. After reviewed the sdk source code , you can try this : `table_service_in.create_table(table_name=tb.name,fail_on_exist=False)`, pls don't forget to accept my answer if it is helpful : )

Comment: You are amazing mate, it worked. Thank you so much